# SPA behaviour for an existing Play Framework webapp

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, playframework, single-page-application, playframework-1.x

We have a complex webapp built in Play Framework (1.*) and we want to move towards a SPA behaviour for it. What JS framework would you recommend for this? Most of the business logic is on the server side (Play controllers).

What would be the pros or cons of using AngularJS or ReactJS, or maybe other framework. How easy would be the integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience , I can recommend the following :

Indeed, You will have two applications :

1. SPA application : Based on [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) framework with [redux](/questions/tagged/redux) .
2. API application : You can any of the famous framework [grails](/questions/tagged/grails) , [express](/questions/tagged/express), [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) , [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) ...etc.

I don't recommend to use Angular, ReactJS is more powerful for many reasons  : namely [virtual-dom](/questions/tagged/virtual-dom)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the act framework at http://actframework.org/, an ex play one that decided to take action, his video for a Rest Service is very impressive: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B2RRSzYeo8c

Answer (score 1):

You can use still Play 1.x as back-end, by converting controllers methods into web-socket events or more simple REST (checkout jersey module, also for inspiration).
After you can make interacting UI HTML SPA based use ReactJS or VueJS (I prefer the second, better separation concerns and better performances).